# magento 2 : Flush static content from admin panel forces to run static:deploy command everytime

Tags: magento2, php, cache

After flushing the static cache files from the `System -> Tools -> Cache Management -> Flush Static Files Cache` from the admin panel...

[image]

magento admin panel is looking like below...

[image]

and for the solution i have to run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
command everytime.

When i installed Magento 2, static files were generated automatically and not by running the command.

What i need to do so that it will start generating the static files automatically after i have flushed them from backend? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

After flushing the static files you have three options in terms of regenerating them:

1) Compile using grunt (Or an alternative JS based less compiler) when working locally on a theme etc

2) Deploy the theme using magento's native setup:static:content-deploy command

3) Server/Client Side compilation

To do option 3, you have to ensure that your environment supports the generation of static files. You can find the setup for these in the nginx.conf.example (if using nginx) and the .htacces.sample (if using apache). For example, the nginx.conf.sample has the following section:

```
location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

This section essentially routes the request for a file through the `pub/static.php` which in turn generates the `pub/static` files with relevant symlinks attached to them (Missing this is most likely the reason yours in not being generated)

Comment: My co-developer is able to generate the static file without executing any of the command mentioned in 1) and 2).As you have suggested to check the above code in nginx.conf.example file, i have checked that.... and the file has same code as you mentioned above.So not the case of 3).
Any other suggestion why it is not generating automatically..as i am new to magento 2....Thanks..

Comment: I've looked at your image, and it seems like you are using walk or xampp. Both or these tend to use apache. You should therefore check to see that your .htaccess at the root of your project has the equivalent code from the .htaccess.sample file

Comment: Wamp* .. Sorry autocorrrect!

Comment: No...there are many diffs....in both the files.....and using xampp...btw...

Comment: Int hat case, confirm that the static file routing section is in there and if it isn't, add it in. Hopefully it does the trick!

Comment: I think it is not in the sample file also...can you suggest where exactly it resides in the sample file..??

Comment: I'm not too sure about apache, sorry! I've only used nginx with Magento 2

Comment: Ok...thanks..for the above suggestion...update if anyone know or find any exact solution or approch regarding this issue....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you run your magento store in **production mode** or **default mode**

In production/default mode once the static file was deleted it never regenerate until you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

You can use the below command to make ensure about what mode are you runnig?

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

If it is **production/default**, change to **developer** mode it will fix your problem

you can use the below command to set developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: From beginning i have set it to the developer mode, one of my co-developer flushes static files in developer mode from admin panel and he gets all the static content automatically by just refreshing the page  ,he does not have to run the command, but in my case i have to run the command...